# Why is this not outputting my user's properties in this ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So the program specifies no errors but it isn't outputting what I want it to. I've made an Array List which should output a user's details which are a username, user Type and a name. I've called the class in my main method but nothing outputs. I'm new to Java so if somebody could help me with how to fix this so that it compiles the user's properties then that would be of great help to myself and possibly other beginners who may come across the same issue. Here is the code:

**UserGroup class (where ArrayList is created**

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserGroup {

    ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    User userOne;

    public void addSampleData(String username, String userType, String name) {

    userGroup.add(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));

}

    public User getUser(int index)  {

    return userGroup.get(0);

}

    public void printusername(){

       for (User x : userGroup) {
    System.out.println(x);
} }
}
```

**User class**

```
package main;
class User {

  String username;
  String userType;
  String name;


    User(String username, String userType, String name) {

    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
    }

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
      return userType;
  }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String setUserType(String admin) {
      return userType = admin;
  }

}
```

**Main class**

```
package main;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    public User callUserGroup; {  

     UserGroup userGroupObject = new UserGroup();

 System.out.println(userGroupObject.getUser(0)); 
 }

}
```

I understand some parts may be irrelevant/not efficient or necessary but I'm a beginner so I'm still getting use to the concepts so some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Add sample data method was not called first. Hence no data in your list

Comment: How would I go about calling it? Thanks for the reply

Comment: you can all it in main class using. userGroupObject.addSampleData("L1",""staff", "LEE");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will break down some problems for the UserGroup class then the main.

**UserGroup Class**: Basically this is a GROUP of Users. So the only property you need is the ArrayList of Users. The main thing missing here is a **constructor**. You have no way to create a new `UserGroup` Object.  I made a constructor that takes nothing and adds some data to the `userGroup`. In the `addSampleData` method you are taking in three string variables, then create a new `User` object with those variables and add it to `userGroup`. Since the `userGroup` Array is made up of `User` objects, I changed the incoming variables from three string variables to one `User` variable.    I changed the name `addSampleData` method to `addUser`. The changes below should address the issues just described.

**Edit:** Added missing getUserGroup() property getter to UserGroup class.

```
ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
// User userOne;
public UserGroup()
{
  addUser(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));
  addUser(new User("XLeeB123", "XStaff", "XLee"));
  addUser(new User("XXLeeB123", "XXStaff", "XXLee"));
}

public void addUser(User inUser)
{
  //userGroup.add(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));
  userGroup.add(inUser);
}
public ArrayList<User> getUserGroup() {
    return userGroup;
}
```

**Main** method: Since the `userGroupObject` has an array of `User` objects I used a for each loop to output all the Users in the `userGroupObject`.

```
//public User callUserGroup;   
UserGroup userGroupObject = new UserGroup();

for (User curUser : userGroupObject.getUserGroup())
{
   System.out.println(curUser.toString()); 
}
```

**EDIT 2:** toString method added to User class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User username=" + username + ", userType=" + userType + ", name=" + name;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, there's just one problem. On line 26 for the callUserGroup method, Java says it cannot find a method for   ".getUserGroup()"?

Comment: That is just the getter for the userGroup array property. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @John123 I also added a toString() method to the User class. So you will also need it to print in main.

Comment: Okay so it compiles now but it outputs "test.User017db9742". I think it's because i haven't printed the toString, Sorry for asking so many questions but do you know how I would do this? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @John123 Yep... add the toString method to the User class. (added to answer)

Comment: This worked, your help is greatly appreciated thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add sampledatamethod was not called first. Hence no data in your list.

You need to add constructor or explicitly call userGroup.addSampleData() method.

Add constructor like this:

```
 public UserGroup() {

    userGroup.add(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));

}
```

Or call in your main class:

```
userGroupObject.addSampleData("L1",""staff", "LEE");
```

Comment: I added userGroupObject.addSampleData("LeeB123","Staff", "Lee"); to the user constructor but nothing has been outputted yet